# How to display tables across multiple tabs with Pandas and Flask

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, flask, tabs

I am searching 2 dataframes and would like to seperate the results tables across tabs.
So far I can only get the 2 tables to display together in the first tab

**Python:**

```
return render_template("drugsafety.html", safetytable=[filtered.to_html(classes='data', index=False), ragfiltered.to_html(classes='data', index=False)], titles=['na', 'First', 'Second'], value=drugnames)
```

**HTML**

```
        <div id="tabs">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#tabs-1">Drug Safety</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tabs-2">RAG</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div id="tabs-1">
                <div class="table_container">
                    {% for table in safetytable %}
                        {{titles[loop.index]}}
                        {{ table|safe }}
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="tabs-2">
                <div class="table_container">
                    {% for table in ragtable %}
                        {{titles[loop.index]}}
                        {{ table|safe }}
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>    
            </div>
        </div>
```

Any help is much appreciated thankyou.

Comment: This will help you: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tabs.asp

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in the .py, safetytable covered both dataframes so needed to seperate them out:

```
return render_template("drugsafety.html", safetytable=[filtered.to_html(classes='data', index=False)], titles=['na', ''],
                                          ragtable=[ragfiltered.to_html(classes='data', index=False)], value=drugnames)
```